# Can the output file object be passed to an input function in SnakeMake?

Tags: input, output, filenames, snakemake

A SnakeMake input function can receive a dictionary of wildcards extracted from the output filename:

```
def inputFunc(wildcards):
    return "test.txt"

rule A:
    output: "{FILE}.{EXT}"
    input: lambda wildcards: inputFunc(wildcards)
```

My question is, is there a way to pass the "output" object, which has the output filenames, to the input function?

Comment: I think the output can be determined based on the wildcards, so having a function of the wildcards as input has, in theory, more flexibility than having a function of the output. That said, there may be cases where it is convenient to use the output...

Comment: This is not possible right now, but it could be easily allowed. What is your motivation?

Comment: I think my motivation at the time was for debugging - I wanted to display the output name from the input function.